# Need help to understand the output and behavior of the code snippet

Tags: python, pytorch

I am new to pytorch and tried to follow this tutorial https://github.com/mrdbourke/pytorch-deep-learning/blob/main/08_pytorch_paper_replicating.ipynb (env: windows 10, editor: visual studio code, python: 3)

```
from helper_functions import download_data, set_seeds, plot_loss_curves
from going_modular import data_setup, engine
from torchinfo import summary
from torchvision import transforms
from torch import nn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
import torchvision

assert int(torch.__version__.split(".")[1]) >= 12 or int(
    torch.__version__.split(".")[0]) == 2, "torch version should be 1.12+"
assert int(torchvision.__version__.split(".")[
           1]) >= 13, "torchvision version should be 0.13+"
print(f"torch version: {torch.__version__}")
print(f"torchvision version: {torchvision.__version__}")


def f():
  device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
  print(device)
  # Download pizza, steak, sushi images from GitHub
  image_path = download_data(source="https://github.com/mrdbourke/pytorch-deep-learning/raw/main/data/pizza_steak_sushi.zip",
                             destination="pizza_steak_sushi")
  print(image_path)
  # Setup directory paths to train and test images
  train_dir = image_path / "train"
  test_dir = image_path / "test"
  print(train_dir, test_dir)

  # Create image size (from Table 3 in the ViT paper)
  IMG_SIZE = 224

  # Create transform pipeline manually
  manual_transforms = transforms.Compose([
      transforms.Resize((IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)),
      transforms.ToTensor(),
  ])
  print(f"Manually created transforms: {manual_transforms}")
  # Set the batch size
  BATCH_SIZE = 32  # this is lower than the ViT paper but it's because we're starting small

  # Create data loaders
  train_dataloader, test_dataloader, class_names = data_setup.create_dataloaders(
      train_dir=train_dir,
      test_dir=test_dir,
      transform=manual_transforms,  # use manually created transforms
      batch_size=BATCH_SIZE
  )

  print(train_dataloader, test_dataloader, class_names)
  # Get a batch of images
  image_batch, label_batch = next(iter(train_dataloader))
  print(image_batch.shape)
  # Get a single image from the batch
  image, label = image_batch[0], label_batch[0]
  # View the batch shapes
  print(image.shape, label)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  f()
```

The output is

```
data\pizza_steak_sushi
data\pizza_steak_sushi\train data\pizza_steak_sushi\test
Manually created transforms: Compose(
    Resize(size=(224, 224), interpolation=bilinear, max_size=None, antialias=warn)
    ToTensor()
)
<torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader object at 0x000002125AAF7910> <torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader object at 0x000002125AAF7850> ['pizza', 'steak', 'sushi']
torch version: 2.1.2+cpu
torchvision version: 0.16.2+cpu
torch version: 2.1.2+cpu
torchvision version: 0.16.2+cpu
torch version: 2.1.2+cpu
torchvision version: 0.16.2+cpu
torch version: 2.1.2+cpu
torchvision version: 0.16.2+cpu
torch.Size([32, 3, 224, 224])
torch.Size([3, 224, 224]) tensor(1)
```

What I am trying to understand -

1. why `torch version: 2.1.2+cpu    torchvision version: 0.16.2+cpu` is displayed multi times?
2. there is a significant delay after this line: `print(train_dataloader, test_dataloader, class_names)`, several seconds on my machine. Given the data is pretty small, is it something related to bullet point 1 (it is loading torch etc again)?

Thanks in advance!

Update: when run in an interactive window in visual studio code, the output seems normal to me (no duplicate).